# Windows Service AutoStart

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

consider a windows service with a setup project , now how can i force the windows service to start after it finish the Installation?

i tried to add project installer and in the commited even i started the service but that would only work if i used InstallUtil im looking for a way to make it while using the Setup Project...

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new custom action that would use the ServiceController class to start your newly created service.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your service to start right after installation you can add the following few code lines. By subscribing to the Committed event you can make sure it starts the service after being installed. Also pay attention to the `service.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;` line, which in its turn takes care of the service to be installed with automatic startup property ON, which makes the service to auto start with system reboot.

```
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        service = new ServiceInstaller();
        service.ServiceName = "MyWCFServer";
        service.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        Installers.Add(process);
        Installers.Add(service);

        service.Committed += new InstallEventHandler(serviceInstaller_Committed);
    }

    void serviceInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceController controller = new ServiceController(service.ServiceName);
        controller.Start();
        controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Johann Blais suggested; First Add a deployment project & Add Custom Action in Both "Install" tab & "Commit" tab do what you require in these Tab, meaning start the service.

Comment: do you mean making a new dll and attach it to custom action ? or exe file ? cause i tried with .bat and it didnt work !

Comment: If you have done everything in OnStart function of Windows Service then just add the Primary Output from your Windows Service Project to the custom Actions.

Comment: i already did that but then what this wont force tyhe service to start after installation

Comment: @Khan i already made the service did everything in that page , why your pointing me to that page ?

Comment: i didn't know that, check this link;  http://www.devnewsgroups.net/windowsforms/t15625-windows-service-autostart-problem.aspx

Comment: actualy i guess this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(VS.80).aspx will work im implementing it now